# How to work the BibTeX?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, tutorials

I have searched the tutorials but have not been successful in understand them. The tutorials always mensionam concepts that I do not know. I would like to understand the basics of BibTeX.

By basics I mean:

- How do I install BiBTeX?
- How to build a file in bib? For this question assume that I already have the bibtex format each reference provided by databases like MathSciNet. See observation 1 below.
- What I write commands in the file format. Tex to call call the format file bib?
- How to exploit the format of the bibliography that comes out in PDF?
  The commands are made in the preamble of the file. Arquifo bib or format. Tex?
- What must be the BiBTeX with biblatex?
- Is there any tutorial (in pdf or video) that teaches step by step how to operate BiBTeX?

**Observation 1** I already have the bibtex format each reference provided by databases like MathSciNet:

```
@article {MR2373353, 
AUTHOR = {Avila, Artur and Lyubich, Mikhail}, 
TITLE = {Hausdorff dimension and conformal measures of {F}eigenbaum {J}ulia sets}, 
JOURNAL = {J. Amer. Math. Soc.}, 
FJOURNAL = {Journal of the American Mathematical Society}, 
VOLUME = {21}, 
YEAR = {2008},
NUMBER = {2}, 
PAGES = {305--363}, 
ISSN = {0894-0347}, 
MRCLASS = {37F35 (37F10 37F25)}, 
MRNUMBER = {2373353 (2009i:37112)}, 
MRREVIEWER = {Feliks Przytycki}, 
DOI = {10.1090/S0894-0347-07-00583-8}, 
URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-07-00583-8}, }
```

Comment: Is this question specific to BibTeX or TeX-based bibliography solutions in general (ie `biblatex`)?  (`biblatex` is going to be significantly easier to customize in many cases, and is more modern.)

Comment: This site is not really suited to answer a list of questions but one question at a time. Additionally have you tried to google "bibtex basics"? The first links answer most of your questions already.

Comment: I have [a section on bibliographies](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/citations.html) in one of my tutorials if that's of any help. It covers the basics of bibtex and biblatex and using jabref to write your `.bib` files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is likely that you already have BibTeX installed as part of your default TeX installation (e.g., if you used MikTeX or TeX Live).  Constructing a `.bib` file is as easy as taking, e.g., the entry you have provided and putting it in a file that ends with the extension `.bib`; put all these specific entries in the same file.  A project-specific `.bib` file could be put in the same folder as your `.tex` file.

So, assuming a `.bib` file called (say) `myexample.bib` with this one entry:

```
@article{MR2373353, 
AUTHOR = {Avila, Artur and Lyubich, Mikhail}, 
TITLE = {Hausdorff dimension and conformal measures of {F}eigenbaum {J}ulia sets}, 
JOURNAL = {J. Amer. Math. Soc.}, 
FJOURNAL = {Journal of the American Mathematical Society}, 
VOLUME = {21}, 
YEAR = {2008},
NUMBER = {2}, 
PAGES = {305--363}, 
ISSN = {0894-0347}, 
MRCLASS = {37F35 (37F10 37F25)}, 
MRNUMBER = {2373353 (2009i:37112)}, 
MRREVIEWER = {Feliks Przytycki}, 
DOI = {10.1090/S0894-0347-07-00583-8}, 
URL = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0894-0347-07-00583-8}, 
}
```

You could 'cite' this reference in a traditional `natbib`-based setup as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

I read \cite{MR2373353}.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{myexample}

\end{document}
```

If the above file were called `mynatbibexample.tex`, you would need to run the following sequence of commands:  `latex mynatbibexample`, `bibtex mynatbibexample`, `latex mynatbibexample`, `latex mynatbibexample`.

If you wanted to do the equivalent, but use `biblatex` instead, you'd use the same `.bib` file, but the `.tex` file would some different commands.  A very simple example could look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex
% backend=biber % <-- biber is a modern replacement for BibTeX designed for use (only) with biblatex
]
{biblatex}
\addbibresource{myexample.bib}

\begin{document}

I read \cite{MR2373353}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The sequence of commands is the same if you use BibTeX: `latex mynatbibexample`, `bibtex mynatbibexample`, `latex mynatbibexample`, `latex mynatbibexample`.  If you wish to try `biber` (and you have it installed), then the sequence would be: latex mynatbibexample`,`biber mynatbibexample`,`latex mynatbibexample`.

Regarding this question:

> How to exploit the format of the bibliography that comes out in PDF?
>   The commands are made in the preamble of the file. Arquifo bib or
>   format. Tex?

The last part is unclear in meaning.  Regarding modifications to the printed format of your bibliography, it really depends on your requirements.  It would be impossible to guess what you are hoping to see, so I advise you to ask separate and more specific follow up questions once you are comfortable with the basics of bibliography generation.

Note also that `biblatex` and `biber` allow for far easier customization, but some publishers may insist on a `BibTeX`-generated bibliography.  In the second case, however, that usually means they can give you a proper **b** ibliography **st** yle file [usually with the extension `.bst`] for you to use.

Comment: I removed temporarily accepted to start the bonus. The bonus will be given to you.

Comment: @Elias -- no worries; and thank you!