# Help with citation

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I would like to cite this article from the web: https://www.economicsnetwork.ac.uk/iree/v4n2/grimes.htm

This is what I have in the body:

```
\indent The proportion of students cheating in schools vary from country to country. Grimes and Rezek found that the proportion of students involved in cheating is higher in six transtional economies, Belarus, Croatia, Kyrgyzstan, Lithuania, Russia and Ukraine, than in the United States. \cite{grimesrezek} \\
```

My bibliography section:

```
\section*{REFERENCES}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\bibliography{eor}

@article{grimesrezek,
    author  = "Paul Grimes", "Jon Rezek"
    title   = "The Determinants of Cheating by High School Economics Students: A Comparative Study of Academic Dishonesty in the Transitional Economies",
    year    = "2005",
    journal = "International Review of Economics Education",
    volume  = "4",
    issue  = "2",
    pages   = "23--45"
}
```

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsart}

% Packages
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{;}{,}{,}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[
  colorlinks=true,
  citecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue,
  linkcolor=blue
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup{labelfont=normalfont,
              labelsep=colon}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\makeatletter
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{1}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\itshape}}
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \edef\@toclevel{\ifnum#2=\@m 0\else\number#2\fi}%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \let\@secnumber\@empty
  \else \@xp\let\@xp\@secnumber\csname the#1\endcsname\fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \edef\@secnumpunct{%
      \ifdim\@tempskipa>\z@ % not a run-in section heading
        \@ifnotempty{#8}{.\@nx\enspace}%
      \else
        \@ifempty{#8}{.}{.\@nx\enspace}%
      \fi
    }%
    \@ifempty{#8}{%
      \ifnum #2=\tw@ \def\@secnumfont{\bfseries}\fi}{}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{%
      \ifnum#2<\@m
        \@ifundefined{#1name}{}{%
          \ignorespaces\csname #1name\endcsname\space
        }%
      \fi
      \@seccntformat{#1}%
    }%
  \fi
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@ % then this is not a run-in section heading
    \begingroup #6\relax
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}{\interlinepenalty\@M #8\par}%
    \endgroup
    \ifnum#2>\@m \else \@tocwrite{#1}{#8}\fi
  \else
  \def\@svsechd{#6\hskip #3\@svsec
    \@ifnotempty{#8}{\ignorespaces#8\unskip
       %\@addpunct.
       }%
    \ifnum#2>\@m \else \@tocwrite{#1}{#8}\fi
  }%
  \fi
  \global\@nobreaktrue
  \@xsect{#5}}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{plain}

\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{12pt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\allowdisplaybreaks[4]

% Commenting/debugging
\let\IG\iffalse
\let\ENDIG\fi

%% Shortcuts
\newcommand{\td}[2]{\dfrac{d #1}{d #2}}
\newcommand{\std}[2]{\dfrac{d^2 #1}{d {#2}^2}}
\newcommand{\ctd}[3]{\dfrac{d^2 #1}{d #2 d #3}}

\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\newcommand{\spd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial {#2}^2}}
\newcommand{\cpd}[3]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial #2 \partial #3}}

\newcommand{\pdi}[2]{\partial #1/\partial #2}

\newcommand{\LR}{\Leftrightarrow}
\newcommand{\Lg}{\mathcal{L}}
\newcommand{\half}{\tfrac{1}{2}}
\newcommand{\eqp}{\phantom{=}}
\newcommand{\eqs}{\buildrel s \over =}
\newcommand{\me}{\mathrm{e}}
```

pdf output:[image]

Comment: Your author line should be: `author  = "Paul Grimes and Jon Rezek",`.

Comment: OK, based on the screenshot you've shown, it looks like you've just put the `.bib` entry (`@article{grimesrezek,...`) somewhere directly in your `.tex` file, which is not the way BibTeX works. [The accepted answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125181/21344) at [How to work the BibTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125158/21344) provides a good overview of the correct process.

Comment: Note that you almost certainly should not have mark up like `\indent` in your document.

Comment: @PaulGessler Not understanding it.

Comment: I want to use \bibliographystyle{dcu}
\bibliography{eor}

Comment: That answer is not working for me.

Comment: Saying that it's "not working" doesn't help us to help you. Your example here also has a lot of unrelated "stuff", it'd be much easier with a basic [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Do you get error messages? If so, what are they? We cannot help if we don't have information about what's going wrong.

Comment: @Paul With my original codes, I am not getting any error messages. It is just not in the proper format, as my attached pdf suggests. And I am not interested in that answer.

Comment: If you have `\bibliography{eor}`, you need to move `@article{grimesrezek,...}` into a text file called `eor.bib` in the same directory as your `.tex` file. For the purposes of this comment/explanation, I assume your `.tex` file is named `example.tex`. Then run `pdflatex example` (without the `.tex` extension), `bibtex exampe`, `pdflatex example`, `pdflatex example`.